# Deploy custom biztalk adapter without install it into GAC

Tags: biztalk

I am not sure whether we can only use registry file to deploy the adapter for BizTalk.
I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can because the Registry entries include ones for the path.

However, I strongly recommend against this.  Adapters and Pipeline Components should be in the GAC.

BizTalk Server itself uses the GAC for Adapters and Pipeline Components.

Comment: I test the Sample SDK code under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\SDK\Samples\AdaptersDevelopment\File Adapter

Comment: Ok...What exactly do you mean by 'doesn't work'?  Using hardcoded paths is fully supported, though not really recommendable.

Comment: After finish registry. I tried to add a new adapter under BizTalk platform settings -> Adapter as I expect this new adapter show come out the drop down menu which allowed to add.

Comment: Use the Wizard to create the .reg file, then you have to import it using both the 32 and 64 but command prompts.  However, it is best to replace the Type name with the Fully Qualified Type name and GAC the Assemblies.